# Adding an arrow to ForeignKey column of Kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid with a ForeignKey column. As it is not obvious for a user that he can click on this column to edit information, I'd like to add an arrow at the end of each row, like on the picture below:

[image: What I want to do]

I tried changing GridForeignKey editor template, however, this will only affect the state when user already clicked on the row in order to edit it. And what I need is to add arrow icon to the "static" state of the field, before it is being edited.

I also tried to play with css classes like k-i-arrow-s,k-state-selected and .k-state-hover. However, it looks like I'm moving in a wrong direction and there must be a more simple way.

The API reference of Kendo grid was not really helpful.

Maybe I can add a template for the default appearance in addition to already existing template for GridForeignKey? Still, can't see how it is possible to use two templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked this question to the Kendo guys and here is the response. 
Their solution indeed worked for me:

I would suggest you to specify a ClientTemplate for the foreign key column. In the template you could add a  tag with k-icon and k-i-arrow-s classes to include the arrow.

E.g.

```
.ClientTemplate("#=data.Employee.EmployeeName# <span class='custom-arrow k-icon k-i-arrow-s'></span>");
```

I also included a custom-arrow class to position the arrow.

E.g.

```
<style>
  .custom-arrow.k-icon
  {
      float: right;
  }
</style>
```